# How can I grab all selectors that are similar to a string in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have a selector that only changes in the last character. I want to grab all the selectors that match the beginning. Here is an example of what I am trying to grab:

```
"button_selector_[number that changes depending on which button]"
```

In something like grok, I could use * to denote that the text that would be where that character is doesn't really matter. Does javascript have something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all elements with an id starting with button_selector_ do:

```
var ... = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="button_selector_"]');
```

And similar for all elements with a class:

```
var ... = document.querySelectorAll('[class^="button_selector_"]');
```

Documentation: [Substring matching attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)